# Kubernetes: Open /certs/tls.crt: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to configure SSL for the Kubernetes Dashboard. Unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
2020/07/16 11:25:44 Creating in-cluster Sidecar client
2020/07/16 11:25:44 Error while loading dashboard server certificates. Reason: open /certs/tls.crt: no such file or directory
```

```
volumeMounts:
            - name: certificates
              mountPath: /certs
              # Create on-disk volume to store exec logs
```

I think that /certs should be mounted, but where should it be mounted?

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are stored as [`secrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/). Then  `secret` can be used and mounted in a `deployment`.

So in your example it would look something like this:

```
...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: certificates
              mountPath: /certs
              # Create on-disk volume to store exec logs
...
      volumes:
        - name: certificates
          secret:
            secretName: certificates
...
```

This is just a short snipped of the whole process of setting up Kubernetes Dashboard v2.0.0 with [recommended.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta8/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml).

If you did used the [`recommended.yaml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta8/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml) then certs are created automatically and stored in memory. Deployment is being created with `args` : `-auto-generate-certificates`

I also recommend reading [How to expose your Kubernetes Dashboard with cert-manager](https://itnext.io/how-to-expose-your-kubernetes-dashboard-with-cert-manager-422ab1e3bf30) as it might be helpful to you.

There already was an issue submitted with a simmilar problem as yours [Couldn't read CA certificate: open : no such file or directory #2518](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2518) but it's regarding Kubernetes v1.7.5

If you have any more issues let me know I'll update the answer if you provide more details.

Comment: ok, can you post output of `kubectl describe secret certificates -n kube-system`. If you do have the dashboard in different namespace, change the command to reflect that. Also which version of Dashboard are you using. Also please post output of `kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system`.